# What does a unresolved external symbol error mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm programming an easy "bid on a house" application in C++. I compile and get this error msg:

```
1>Hus.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall 
Bud::Bud(void)" (??0Bud@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall 
Hus::Hus(int,class Person,class std::basic_string<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" 
(??0Hus@@QAE@HVPerson@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>F:\c++\prosjekter\Øving 4\Ov4Oppg1\Debug\Ov4Oppg1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 
unresolved externals
```

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not linking with Bud.obj which is required in Hus.obj...?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because you haven't implemented

```
Bud::Bud()
```

which you call from `Hus::Hus()`.

You most likely have something like:

```
class Bud
{
public:
   Bud();
}
```

and forgot to implement the constructor. You need to add

```
Bud::Bud() 
{
   //whatever
}
```

to an implementation file, compile and link to the obj file generated.

Comment: Yeah I actually did. Thank you alot m8 :-)

Comment: @user1264836 you actually did what?

Comment: I have 1 constructor that I use, which is not like the default constructor. But I declared an empty constructor in the header file, because of an declaration of an Bud table. So i had forgotten the implementation of this empty constructor in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error caused by a simple error: I forgot to implement one of my functions in the cpp file.
When a object of other class called one object of this class that I've forgot to implement, this error appeared.
I think that the error appears like a "linking error" because my function returns a type defined in other file of my project.

Noobie error... But it can be useful for someone...